# two column two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID  mobileno        dateofregistration       registrationstate 
44  1674174925  2011-04-18 10:17:30.670         0
45  1677864168  2011-03-31 10:20:22.450         1
46  1677864161  2011-04-18 20:47:35.293         0
47  1674174925  2011-03-29 09:28:55.200         1
48  1674174967  2011-03-29 09:28:55.100         1
```

1. I've to find how many registrationstate=1 in a given period
2. how many registrationstate changed from 0 to 1 in the same above given period.

> ```
> SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(10), dateofregistration, 103) AS Date
>         , COUNT(1) AS Subbase
>         , SUM(CASE WHEN registrationstate='1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NewAct
>         , SUM(CASE WHEN (registrationstate='0' and registrationstate='1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SuccessRen
> FROM    tbl_User 
> GROUP BY
>         CONVERT(varchar(10), dateofregistration, 103)
> ORDER BY 
>         1
> ```

Comment: How can one tell that a registration state changed from 0 to 1?

Comment: @Will A: Probably based on the previous (by date) value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a [calendar table](http://www.google.com/search?q=sql%20calendar%20table&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) and using that to join help you out for your first query.  Define your periods in the calendar table and then it is a simple matter of some joins and a count statement grouping by your calendar table period.

The second query would be similar, but I would make a subquery of mobilenumbers = 0 and join all the 1's to that subquery for the timeperiod.

During my coding of the solution, I'm sure I'd discover I was mistaken about a few of these approaches ;)